# Jenkins build job after merging pull request in Github

Tags: github, jenkins, merge, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I wanted to know how I can build a Jenkins job right after merging a pull request into the master branch.

I'm very new in this Jenkins/Github thing and wanted to know how/if it's possible to achieve this without using webhooks.

Best Regards

Luca

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a `CI` file. Basically it's a file that tells Jenkins what it can do, how to do it and when to do it. You then create a build job that should be run on `master` branch and set its firing hook as automatic . That's a **tl;dr** version that sketches how it's done in general. For specifics you have to check a manual.

Comment: Is there also an other way? I'm really limited with my abilities to config Jenkins in any way such as creating a CI file...